# How do I enable old style collections in my Plone 4.3.9 site?

Tags: plone

Can I use old style collections rather than the new collection? If so, how?

Comment: Now published as an add-on, for comfy replication: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/adi.enabletopics

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to `http://[HOST]/[PLONESITE_ID]/@@types-controlpanel?type_id=Topic`, check the box where it says "Globally addable" and hit the "Apply Changes" on bottom of the form.

Programatically reproducable by adding `/profiles/default/Topic.xml` to your addon with the following content:

```
<object name="Topic">
<!-- Enable old-style-collections 
     By default turned off since >= Plone-4.1 -->
  <property name="global_allow">True</property>
</object>
```

To turn off the new-style-collections, you can do the same procedure, just replace "Topic" with "Collection" and set "global_allow" to False.

If you also want be able to define which fields are available as a choosable criterion in a collection's edit-mode, via the site's UI, go to `http://[HOST]/[PLONESITE_ID]/portal_controlpanel/manage_editActionsForm` and check "Collections (old style)" entry, then "Collections (old style)" will become visible for configuration in the site's controlpanel, accessible via `http://[HOST]/[PLONESITE_ID]/@@overview-controlpanel`.

Also these settings can be reproduced programatically via a `profiles/default/portal_atct`, you can export the relevant xml-file via `http://[HOST]/[PLONESITE_ID]/portal_setup/manage_main`, or have a look at this example for an orientation: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ida/adi/master/adi.tickets/adi/tickets/profiles/default/portal_atct.xml

Note: In case you are adding new fields as criteria here, you'll need to register them in the catalogue also, via `profiles/default/catalog.xml`, another example for that case: https://github.com/ida/adi/blob/master/adi.tickets/adi/tickets/profiles/default/catalog.xml

Furthermore: If you want to allow visitors to change the criteria's values to search for, on the fly via the UI – a search-form in other words – look at [collective.formcriteria](https://github.com/collective/collective.formcriteria), written by [Ross Patterson](http://rpatterson.net/).

Comment: @keul: Thanks for the complementing the answer! Would like to share the points of this answer with you...  At SO-builders: You got a feature-request here :-)